# DJ Software recommendation

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation

I am using virtual DJ at my uncle's house but want to use it on Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell Netbook. I'm looking for a software recommendation **other than** Mixxx and DJ Play. I don't like them.

Answer (score 0):

Try Xwax.

> xwax is an open-source Digital Vinyl System (DVS) for Linux. It allows
>   DJs and turntablists to playback digital audio files (MP3, Ogg Vorbis,
>   FLAC, AAC and more), controlled using a normal pair of turntables via
>   timecoded vinyls.
>
> It's designed for both beat mixing and scratch mixing. Needle drops,
>   pitch changes, scratching, spinbacks and rewinds are all supported,
>   and feel just like the audio is pressed onto the vinyl
>   itself.<sup>[xwax](http://xwax.org/)</sup>

To download, and more information see their [website](http://xwax.org/)